# XPath: How do I find a frame with this name?

Tags: xpath, selenium

For the purposes of using xpath in a Selenium test, how do I write an Xpath expression where the name of my frame is "sb_player"?  In my Fierbug console, I get this from my doc ...

```
window.frames[1].name
"sb-player"
```

but I can't figure out an equivalent expression in Xpath to identify the frmae (//frames[1] doesn't work).

Thanks for your help, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try xpath like something  below?

```
//frame[name='sb_player']
```